# cant get array to update properly

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to make a program that loops through a string and count how many of each letter is used. Problem is that i cant get the array to save it properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    string textRad = "";
    int histogram[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];

    getline(cin, textRad);

    berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);

    cout << histogram[0] << endl;
    cout << histogram[2];

    return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], string textRad) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++) 
    {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < textRad.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; j++)
        {
            int antal = 0;
            string alfabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

            if(char(toupper(textRad.at(i))) == alfabet.at(j))
            {
                antal++;
            }
            histogram[j] = antal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with each iteration of j, `antal` will start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use the antal variable is wrong. you would never get more then 1 for each letter. Something like this should work better:

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], string textRad) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++) 
    {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < textRad.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; j++)
        {
            string alfabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

            if(char(toupper(textRad.at(i))) == alfabet.at(j))
            {
                histogram[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i would also recommend using english for variables/method names.

Answer (score 1):

Taking account of Javid's and Tjofras' answers here is a complete, simpler, and safer example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void berakna_histogram_abs(std::vector<int>& histogram, const std::string& textRad);

int main() {

    const int ANTAL_BOKSTAVER = 26; //Assumed value.

    std::string textRad;
    std::vector<int> histogram(ANTAL_BOKSTAVER, 0);

    std::getline(std::cin, textRad);

    std::transform(textRad.begin(), textRad.end(), textRad.begin(), toupper);
    berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);

    std::cout << histogram[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << histogram[2];

    return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(std::vector<int>& histogram, const std::string& textRad) {

    static std::string alfabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    std::size_t s = alfabet.length();
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        histogram[i] = std::count(test_string.begin(), test_string.end(), alfabet[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{

    string textRad = "";
    int histogram[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];

    getline(cin, textRad);

    berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);


    cout << histogram[0] << endl;
    cout << histogram[2];

    return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], string textRad) {

    for(int i = 0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++)
        histogram[i] = 0;

    string alfabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(int i = 0; i < textRad.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < alfabet.length(); j++)
            if(char(toupper(textRad.at(i))) == alfabet.at(j))
                histogram[j]++;
    }

}
```